# Able to access internet, cannot ping router or local network

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I have Arch Linux installed on a box, with the `6.1.12-1-lts` kernel. I have `dhcpcd` and `NetworkManager` installed, as well as a VPN client, and am able to access the internet through my connection. I don't have `ufw` installed. There are no warnings for either `dhcpcd` or `NetworkManager` and I have no specific firewall rules configured on the router (Edgerouter X).

However, I cannot access my router, or other machines on my network, consistently from this box. I have been able to, on occasion, in the past, but not any more. Here are the outputs that might help. What am I missing?

`ip addr`

(permaddr removed, vpn ip blanked)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp89s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:21:0b:33:32:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.75/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp89s0
       valid_lft 85461sec preferred_lft 85461sec
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5e:17:af:6b:7c:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr
4: nordlynx: <POINTOPOINT,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet xx.xx.xx.xx/32 scope global nordlynx
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip neigh`

```
192.168.1.1 dev enp89s0 lladdr 78:8a:20:be:20:63 REACHABLE 
192.168.1.47 dev enp89s0 lladdr 90:09:d0:0a:2b:4f STALE
```

`sudo iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             connmark match  0xe1f1 /* nordvpn */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             connmark match  0xe1f1 /* nordvpn */
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* nordvpn */
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* nordvpn */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0xe1f1 /* nordvpn */ CONNMARK save
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             connmark match  0xe1f1 /* nordvpn */
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0xe1f1 /* nordvpn */ CONNMARK save
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             connmark match  0xe1f1 /* nordvpn */
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* nordvpn */
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* nordvpn */
```

`tracepath 192.168.1.1`

```
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  send failed
 1:  send failed
     Resume: pmtu 1500
```

`ip route show`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp89s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.75 metric 1002 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp89s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.75 metric 20100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp89s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.75 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp89s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.75 metric 1002 
192.168.1.1 dev enp89s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.75 metric 100 
192.168.1.47 dev enp89s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.75 metric 100
```

`systemctl status dhcpcd`

```
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-02-22 16:48:48; 21min ago
    Process: 530 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 533 (dhcpcd)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 38095)
     Memory: 2.4M
        CPU: 96ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
             ├─533 "dhcpcd: [manager] [ip4] [ip6]"
             ├─534 "dhcpcd: [privileged proxy]"
             ├─535 "dhcpcd: [network proxy]"
             ├─536 "dhcpcd: [control proxy]"
             └─645 "dhcpcd: [BPF ARP] enp89s0 192.168.1.75"
```

`systemctl status NetworkManager`

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-02-22 16:48:47; 21min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 4915 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 38095)
     Memory: 6.1M
        CPU: 94ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─4915 /usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
```

Comment: Disable your VPN - can you now access your local network? If yes, you're likely to have same issue I did, and the solution is whitelisting your local network in the VPN client. My experience was with NordVPN.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I was using my VPN on another distro before without needing to whitelist it (as far as I remember), so it wouldn't have even come up as a solution.

Comment: LOL yeah - I've had my VPN for several years, and bumped into this first time like two months ago :-D Do feel free to write an answer, and drop back in a couple of days to accept it as well. Include your VPN provider, and mention my experience with NordVPN as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with my VPN, which was NordVPN, which while active, was blocking access. It would also block access after disabling the VPN, after being active.

Accessing the other machines only worked when my VPN had not been active originally and would stop after activating.

Whitelisting my local subnet `192.168.1.0/24` fixed the issue for me.